# .net Core *.csproj based projects on VSTS - How do I publish my xUnit Test Results?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, xunit, csproj

It used to be, back in the project.json world of dotnet core, that a simple...

```
dotnet test -xml myfile.xml
```

would output a test file you could upload in VSTS. This doesn't work anymore and I can't find any help as to what should work. I have upgraded my project but I now have a ton of tests with no output which is rather useless.

Has anyone worked through this problem?

I found this article...

https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-test-results-in-vsts.html

But that doesn't apply with .net core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **.NET Core** task and **Publish Test Results** task to publish your xunit test results. Detail settings as below:

**.NET Core**

Command: `test`

Project(s): specify the test csproj file(s), such as `**/*Tests/*.csproj`

Arguments: `--logger "trx;LogFileName=myfile.xml"`

**Publish Test Results**

Test Result Format: `VSTest`

Test Results Files: `**/myfile.xml`

Comment: This doesn't work. I am unable to specify the xml output from dot net test to publish as the - xml option is no longer valid.

Comment: What's the log after you used Publish test results?

Comment: There are no test results to publish as dot net test on its own does not generate an output file. If the new command does this but with a different filename then that could help.

Comment: you need to add `--logger trx` when to generate trx xml logs during `dotnet test` executions.

Comment: Great - I'll give this a try later

Comment: Works like a charm.